# Use a variable to choose a dictionary to search in Python 3 and Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have got some customers, e.g. `customer1`. And I have stored their data in a dictionary like this:

```
customer1 = {"Age": 20, "Gender": "Male",}
```

I want to have a Tkinter entry box and a text variable called `searchterm`:

```
searchterm = StringVar()
entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=searchterm)
```

Then I want to be able to find the dictionary using the value typed in and then display the data in a text widget.

I'm new to python so please help.

Comment: Don't use per-customer variables. Use a dictionary instead; `customers = {}` then `customers['customer1'] = {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a frame called frame1

```
#Create Text to present result and Entry for input

text1 = Text(frame1,bg="white",width=60)
entry1 = Entry(frame1,bg="yellow")

#The handler necessary to process input

def handler1(event):
        text1.delete(1.0,END)
        data=entry1.get()
        #What ever you want to do with data#
        #get result...#
        text1.insert(result)

#A button to engage your function with input

b1=Button(self,text="Open",width=20)
b1.bind("<Button-1>",handler1)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I explained it properly. This is the code I have already: from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame = Frame()

word1 = StringVar()

customer1 = {'Lawn_Area': '20 m2', 'Lawn_Cost': '£30',}

entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=word1)
entry.pack()

text = Text(frame, width=40, height=10)
text.pack()

diction = word1.get()

text.insert('1.0', diction.items())

root.mainloop()

Comment: What is the format of your dictionary with all the customers? Or where are your customers data? In a file?

Comment: Sorry I do not quite get what you mean?

Comment: First of all, you do not call the dictionary properly.

Comment: It is difficult to read your code properly but as I see you never make a call to the customers dictionary...you write text.insert('1.0', diction.items()) but diction is a string that is your input not a dictionary, that is why you should probably get an Error. THe way I see it you must use diction to make a call from a collection of customers...meaning what Martijn Pieters mentioned above...for example text.insert('1.0', customers[diction]) where customers = {customer1, customer2, ...}

Comment: Correction...I meant:customers = {'customer1':{'Lawn_Area': '20 m2', 'Lawn_Cost': '£30',}, 'customer2':...}